# how to link to a page loaded by jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I am aming to create a simple photography portfolio website. Basically I wanna show four slideshows on four pages but I'm just loading a slideshow into a div with jquery when the user clicks the menu.

```
<div id="slideshow"><img src="1.jpg">...</div>
```

So I'm changing the content if the "slideshow" `div`. But now I kinda need to be able to provide an external link to each slideshow like if it was standalone html like `example.com/abcd.html`.

Any ideas appreciated.

PS: in the end jquery `.load()` is not essential, I just wanna keep my URL clean that's why I'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Send the names of all images to the script and load those upon initialization.
2. Use Javascript to retrieve the URL's GET parameters and use those to identify the slideshow that you want to display by a "slideshow id". [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) explains how. Once you have the slideshow id, you can just request all pictures of that guy from the server using a special request, like `$.get("slideshow_data?id=" + slideShowId)`.

It's generally faster to have the server send all pictures in one request, rather than creating a single request for every picture.